# Devemos editar perguntas em inglês, traduzindo-as?

Tags: debate

Já mais de uma vez vi usuários editando questões que estavam com o texto em inglês para o português e me levantou uma questão: Devemos editar as questões que estão em outras línguas para o português?

Acredito que tenha tanto o lado bom, de termos uma quantidade ainda maior de conteúdo, mais respostas, etc. Entretanto, me preocupa que muitos usuários que procuram respostas no SOEn passem a ter preguiça de traduzir e apenas copiem e colem suas questões, esperando que outros usuários traduzam sua questão. Além de tornar desnecessário o sinalizador de fora do escopo do site.

Enfim, como a comunidade deverá proceder nesses casos?